# HTML/Javascript form - How to make a new div element that overlays?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really confused on how to go about this.

What I'm trying to do is, have a form in HTML (not `<form>`), just a bunch of `<input>` tags with a `<button>`.

Basically, in the `javascript` code, there's an event listener that activates the `MakeCard()` method, when the `<button>` is pressed.

The `MakeCard()` method is supposed to then replace the form (in the HTML body) with a `<div>` that has it's own random stuff.

How do I make this system work? Please no `JQuery` and other such libraries. I'm only allowed to use `DOM`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function(){

        var nameOfRecipient = document.getElementById("nameOfRecipient");
        var colorInfo = document.getElementById("colorInformation");
        var fontSize = document.getElementById("fontSize");

        var resultNameOfRecipient = document.getElementById("resultNameOfRecipient");
        var resultColorInfo = document.getElementById("resultColorInformation");
        var resultFontSize = document.getElementById("resultFontSize");

        function MakeCard(){
            // Make the card

            // Show the results
            ShowResults();
        }

        function ShowResults(){
            // Show the user choices
            resultNameOfRecipient.innerHTML = nameOfRecipient.value;
            resultColorInfo.innerHTML = colorInfo.value;
            resultFontSize.innerHTML = fontSize.value;
        }

        document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", MakeCard);

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerContainer">
        Welcome to the Card Maker!
    </div>
    <div id="formContainer">
        <p>Name of recipient<input type="text" id="nameOfRecipient"></p>
        <p>Color Information<input type="text" id="colorInformation"></p>
        <p>Font Size<input type="number" id="fontSize"></p>
        <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Make Card!">
    </div>
    <div id="resultContainer">
        <p id="resultNameOfRecipient"></p>
        <p id="resultColorInformation"></p>
        <p id="resultFontSize"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

PLEASE IGNORE THE LAST DIV WITH `ID="resultContainer"` and ignore all the variables that have the `result` in front. That stuff is other extra stuff.

It would be amazing if I could just know how to make an entirely new div that REPLACES the div with `ID="formContainer"`.

Comment: By random stuff do you mean like a thank you message at its simplest? If that's the case [here is a jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/dd4x8qdt/) demonstrating how you would 1. create a new element in js and 2. replace the existing div with `id="formContainer"` with another div with the same id. I wrapped the form container in another container called, for lack of a better name, formContainerContainer though that can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: Why use listeners when you can use onclick tags? Set the button like this, and change the listener to a dedicated function:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
```

becomes

```
function myfunction() {
```

and don't forget to change the end of the script from }); to }..

Also, remove the listener from the button, which is this line.

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", MakeCard);
```

And add an onclick event to the button, and change it to a button type, to make sure it doesn't submit:

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton" onclick="myfunction()">Make Card!</button>
```

Secondly: You've set variables to actual HTML elements, which would show something like: HTML[buttonElement]... I'm assuming what you want is what was typed in the element, which is the "value" tag. You would get that by changing the variables to this:

```
 var nameOfRecipient = document.getElementById("nameOfRecipient").value;
        var colorInfo = document.getElementById("colorInformation").value;
        var fontSize = document.getElementById("fontSize").value;

        var resultNameOfRecipient = document.getElementById("resultNameOfRecipient").value;
        var resultColorInfo = document.getElementById("resultColorInformation").value;
        var resultFontSize = document.getElementById("resultFontSize").value;
```

So now that we've tidy'd up your syntax and stuff, I wanna get on to the part where you said you wanted to replace the DIV. Here's my way of doing it:

I would give every element in the DIV an ID (other than the button, we've already discussed that).

```
<p id="nameofrecipentp">Name of recipient<input type="text" id="nameOfRecipient"></p>
        <p id="colorinformationp">Color Information<input type="text" id="colorInformation"></p>
        <p id="fontsizep">Font Size<input type="number" id="fontSize"></p>
```

You could then call a function when the function myfunction() is called.

```
function myfunction() {
replacediv()
```

And define replacediv() to replace all the elements in the form to whatever you'd like.

```
function replacediv() {
document.getElementById("nameofrecipentp").innerHTML = 
"Enter your data here"
document.getElementById("colorinformationp").innerHTML = 
"Enter your data here, for the color information"
document.getElementById("fontsizep").innerHTML = 
"enter your data here for font size"
}
```

I think I pretty much covered everything. If you still need help, tell me.